# How to find the limit of a convergent matrix?

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to learn how to show a series of matrices is convergent and find the limit. However my numerical analysis books fail to mention this and I cannot find any relevant material online! Anyway say I had

$\sum_{k=0}^ \infty A^K$, where A = $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & -2 & -1\\0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

How would i show that the series of matrrices converges and compute its limit?

Would I use some kind of induction? Some help would be amazing, many thanks!

Comment: See my last update. Got it? You just take the infinitie sum over **each** $a_{i,j}$ in the matrix. Is that clear? Regards

Comment: aaah just about almost there! just a lack of resources!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

1. How would you first write the matrix power $A^K$?
2. Once you have an expression for $A^K$, you can take the sum to each $a_{i,j}$ in your 3x3. Of course four of the terms are immediately known! Also, two of terms in the diagonal are the same, so you would be finding the sum of four expressions that are sums over $k$.

**Update**

So, here our sum is:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} & -2 & -1\\0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \begin{bmatrix}(-1/2)^k & \left(\frac{4}{5}\right) 3^{1-k} ((-3/2)^k-1) & (-1)^k 2^{1-k} k \\ 0 & 3^{-k} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & (-1/2)^k)\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, how do you evaluate each of these sums and do they each converge?

**Update 2**

You should get:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{3} & -2 & -\frac{4}{9}\\0 & \frac{3}{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$

I would also recommend taking this answer and seeing how the other answers apply.

Comment: $\quad\ddot\smile\quad$

Comment: but some of them converge to 0 and some of them alternate between positive and negative and thus are not convergent or divergent! is this definately cnvergent?

Comment: @user67411: See update

Comment: i just realised where i have been going wrong... ooops! many thanks! :)

Comment: @user67411: You are very welcome! Please report back about your convergence result! Regards

Comment: they each converge to 0 so surely the sum of matrices converges to 0 too?

Comment: @user67411: You are finding their infinite sum, not their limit. :-)

Comment: aaahh how do i find the infinite sum of a matrice? do i have to find the eigen value of the matrice? ill have a read and see if i can find out...

Comment: $\ddot\smile$. This is from me to you.

Comment: @BabakS.: thank you my friend! Great to see you again!

Answer (score 5):

Choose any algebra norm $||.||$ and if $||A||<1$ then the geometric series 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty ||A||^k$$
is convergent so the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k$ is normal convergent and then it's convergent.

One possible method to calulate the limit: let $\pi_A$ the minimal polynomial of $A$ and by the Euclidean division we have
$$x^k=Q(x)\pi_A(x)+R_k(x)$$
with $\deg(R_k)<\deg(\pi_A)$
and we have $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty R_k(A)$$
and the last sum is more simple to calculate.

**Added**
In our case, the matrix $A$ is triangular and since $(A+\frac{1}{2}I_3)(A-\frac{1}{3}I_3)\neq0$ so we can see easly that the minimal polynomial is
$$\pi_A(x)=\frac{1}{12}(3x-1)(2x+1)^2$$
hence in the Euclidean division the remainder polynomial is
$$R_k(x)=a_k x^2+b_k x+c_k$$
and we have
$$\begin{align}\\
\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k&=a_k/9+b_k/3+c_k\\
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k&=a_k/4-b_k/2+c_k\\
k\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^{k-1}&=-a_k+b_k\\
\end{align}$$
so we solve the above system for $a_k,b_k$ and $c_k$ and finally we find
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)A^2+\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k\right)A+\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\right)I_3$$

Comment: but i litterally have no idea about convergent matrices, i have done convergence in analysis with normal series and sequences and can prove a series or sequence is convergent using an epsilon proof, but i really dont get this at all, but only as i have no reference for it! could you please suggest a page that may have the desired information?

Comment: You can see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics) and particulary the item series in banach spaces.

Comment: im using this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix as a guide but i am getting a different value for the limit of each series in the matrice! should i  not be doing it using this?

Comment: @user67411 I added the method of calculus of the sum and I think you can complete all necessary calculus.

Comment: okay i think i get it now! the limits of all of the k series is 0 thus convergent and do i need to find the eigen values also? thank you!

Comment: I think you've said minimal polynomial when you meant chracteristic polynomial. Otherwise, you need a little extra argument to deduce it from simply looking at the diagonal. Note: I know that minimal=characteristic polynomial in this special case.

Comment: @julien I know that the use of characteristic polynomial gives the same result but in general the use of minimal polynomial is better thanks to its degree which's generally less than $chi_A$, and obviously I didn't deduce it from simply looking at the diagonal but also $(A+\frac{1}{2}I)(A-\frac{1}{3}I)\neq0$

Comment: I know that you know and that you did not deduce it like that, of course. If you really meant minimal, it would probably be good to add that $(A+1/2)(A-1/3)\neq 0$ in your argument for the sake of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

A special solution to this problem:

You may write $A = D+N$, where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ is nilpotent in an obvious way. Then it is easy to see (either by a direct calculation or by the celebrated Cayley-Hamilton theorem) that $N^3 = O$ and thus we can simply $A^k$ as

$$ A^k = D^k + kD^{k-1}N + \frac{k(k-1)}{2}D^{k-2}N^2. $$

Now both the convergence and the summation value can be easily analyzed from the knowledge on power series in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: $D$ and $N$ do not commute, if by $N$ you meant what I think you meant.

Comment: @julien, you're right. I was careless. Maybe we can use Cayley-Hamilton theorem to establish a 3rd order linear homogeneous recurrence relation of $(A^k)$ to obtain a formula for $A^k$, though the solution now becomes much complex.

Comment: That's what Sami Ben Romdhane did. It is a pretty good way, indeed.